# GeoServer meta-tile configuration

Tags: openlayers, geoserver, geowebcache

Can someone point me in the right direction? Somewhat new to GIS / GeoServer. I'm attempting to configure meta-tiling on GeoserverWebCache as described [here](https://www.geowebcache.org/docs/current/concepts/metatiles.html). We've run into the duplicate label problem with out vector tiles. Currently we make requests via a proxy from OpenLayers in the following way :

Openlayers :

```
 const source = new VectorTileSource({
      format: new MVT(),
      url: this.getDataSourceUrl(), <--- Goes to to proxy below
      tileLoadFunction: this.getTileLoadFunction(),
 });
```

Proxy

```
uriBuilder
.path("/geoserver/gwc/service/tms/1.0.0/{layerName}/{zoom}/{x}/{y}.{format}").build("search:$layerName@EPSG%3A900913@pbf", zoom, x, y, format)
```

My goal is to render one label for each vector, ideally without using an additional layer just for the labels.

[image]

Configuring styles on geoserver is not an option for me.

Any thoughts on how I might achieve displaying a singular label?